# Where should I add extra fields to WooCommerce products in front end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm working on a online prescription glasses woocommerce site. I need to create almost 10 custom fields(shpere, cylinder.. for both eyes ) and some conditional logic.

I have tried to create a new page after Add to cart where i will get custom fields inputs from user. but haven't found any helpful article or code. main reason i didn't tried to put these on Single Product page is that it might become to congested.

i need suggestion if it is a good approach to create a page after Add to cart or should i add it on single product page. or what is best possible way to add the custom fields

Comment: You should look to Woocommerce template files… With simple products, use a custom function on  `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` action hook | On variable products,  use a custom function on  `woocommerce_before_single_variation` action hook … No page is needed. So you can search in those related threads: For [simple products](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button+field) or for [variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_before_single_variation)

Comment: thanks @LoicTheAztec i think overriding woocommerce template is a better option

Comment: Sorry but the best option is first to use hooks and if it's not possible, then to use templates.